# How does kotlin's htmlx builder works under the hood exactly?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

This is a fragment that explains some part of htmlx builder (from documentation):

```
protected fun <T : Element> initTag(tag: T, init: T.() -> Unit): T {
    tag.init()
    children.add(tag)
    return tag
}
```

The main point is `children.add(tag)` , so we can then declare :

```
html {
    head {}
    body {}
}
```

because head and body are member functions of html.
But what about **DIV** tag ? I can declare div everywhere, furthermore i can write something like this :

```
someEnclosingTag { (1..3).forEach { div {+"MyCustomDivFromEverywhere"}  }}
```

**How does enclosing lambda knows about "child" lambdas (and respectively, add's 'child' tag to whole html) that can be declared everywhere ?**

Please, correct me, if i'm wrong somewhere.

**UPDATE**

based on answer, i ended with the following dirty-dummy code, that shows function scopes (some aspects of closure's) and implicit receiver omission (Hope it can somehow help someone):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Child().childFun {
        /*childFun lambda receiver implements parent1Fun lambda receiver, so the receiver can be omitted*/
        parent1Fun {
            /*call from Child.() -> Unit receiver*/
            someIntrestingFun()
        }
        /*same as with parent1Fun*/
        parent2Fun {
            /*call from Child.() -> Unit receiver*/
            someIntrestingFun()
        }
    }
}

fun Child.childFun(lambda: Child.() -> Unit): Child = genericFun(Child(), lambda)

fun ParentInt1.parent1Fun(lambda: ParentInt1.() -> Unit): ParentInt1 = genericFun(Child(), lambda)

fun ParentInt2.parent2Fun(lambda: ParentInt2.() -> Unit): ParentInt2 = genericFun(Child(), lambda)

fun <T> genericFun(instance:T, lambda:T.() -> Unit): T {
    instance.lambda()
    return instance
}

interface ParentInt1
interface ParentInt2

class Child : ParentInt1, ParentInt2 {
    fun someIntrestingFun() { println(this) }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more about the techniques of building such DSLs in the language reference, see: [Type-Safe Builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html), and that page gives an example HTML builder (though kotlinx.html is more complicated).

> How does enclosing lambda knows about "child" lambdas that can be declared everywhere?

It's how the function resolution works: when you have nested lambdas, with receiver or not, in the inner ones you can call member/extension functions on the receivers of the outer ones<sup>(*)</sup>, here's a very synthetic example:

```
with(arrayListOf<String>()) {
    with(hashMapOf<Int, String>()) {
        // You can call both functions of `ArrayList` and `HashMap`:
        add("foo")
        put(1, "bar")

        // Even in the nested lambdas with no receiver:
        baz.forEach { put(it, "it = $it") }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>(*): In advanced DSLs, the scope can be restricted with [`@DslMarker`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html#scope-control-dslmarker-since-11), to avoid accidentally calling a function on a receiver from the outer scope.</sup>

Comment: Thank !!! I read about Type-Safe Builders a lot, but there are not enough information about function resolution mechanism. Can you please provide some reference that will help me dive deeper. Also if i'm right - receiver's omission in nested lambdas refers to the same mechanism.

Comment: There's a work-in-progress specification (quite raw at the moment, but still precise in what it tells) that explains some of the function resolution logic: [(here)](http://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/#_best_candidate). Apart from that, I know of no good source of profound knowledge. Searching for articles about building Kotlin DSLs may help you with examples though.